# In what order does Visual Studio compile source files?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, build, dependencies

I have a C++ library project in Visual Studio 2012, with these files

```
A.h, A.cpp: defines function Do_A();
B.h, B.cpp: defines function Do_B();
C.h, C.cpp: defines function Do_C();
```

The functions are implemented like this

```
void Do_A()
{
      Do_B();
}

void Do_B()
{
      Do_C();
}

void Do_C()
{
     printf("Do C");
}
```

Here I want to force the dependency among A, B, C. Then I build.

But when looking at Output window, I see

```
A.cpp
B.cpp
C.cpp
```

Why is A compiled first? What affect the compile order of source files?

Comment: Incidentally, why do you care about compilation order?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo sometimes I see VS compile one file before another, so I wonder

Comment: You cannot force a build order.  What you are looking for is a *function prototype*.  You normally put those in a .h file.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to force, just want to understant it. What do you mean by function prototype ?

Comment: Just google it, "c++ function prototype".  Also covered in your C++ language book, surely you have one?

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I've already known about function prototype, but still don't know how it is related to compile order ?

Comment: *You cannot force the build order*.  With function prototypes in .h files, *you don't care about the build order*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dependency is at link time, not compile time (thus won't show here).

The position inside the build script is what affects the compile order (and there is no assumption on that, other than compile time dependencies), but that's partly untrue as build could be parallelized. That is, A and B could be built on two different cores, at the same time.